# Helm Hook Annotations not loaded in Kubernetes Configmaps

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap, daemonset

I am using two configmaps - one for install and one for uninstall / delete and to trigger actions before delete , I defined helm hooks in the uninstall daemonset **annotations**. Below is the code for the uninstall daemonset written in yaml

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: DaemonSet
    metadata:
      name: delete-pack
      namespace: mynamespace
      labels:
        app: <ex>
        chart: <ex>
      annotations:
        "helm.sh/hook": pre-delete
        "helm.sh/hook-weight": "-10"
        "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": hook-succeeded,before-hook-creation,hook-failed
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: <ex>
```

The rest of the yaml file is of regular template of defining mount volume etc. When running the install command, the configmaps are registered in the namespace and while checking the namespace with **kubectl describe configmaps -n mynamespace**, for the **delete-pack** configmap, this is the following output:

```
    Name:         delete-pack
    Labels:       app=sample
                  chart=sample
    Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: sample
```

The hook definitions are not loaded, due to which, while running delete, the configmaps are removed and the hook terminates with an error stating

```
    configmap "delete-pack" not found
```

and the configmaps are cleared from the namespace. The hook becomes an **orphanedPod** and is deleted without the pre-delete actions defined being executed.

I find the reason to be the annotations not loaded along with the configmap name in the namespace. What could be the reason for the helm hooks to not be registered? Is there a fundamental error in Kubernetes installation?

Could you also please point me towards any further steps for debug?

**UPDATE**

The Configmap of **delete-pack** did not have the annotations. But when added, **delete-pack** does not get registered at all in the configmaps of the name space. (i.e)

```
    Name:         pack
    Labels:       app=sample
                  chart=sample
    Annotations:  meta.helm.sh/release-name: sample

    <delete-pack data absent>
```

Comment: Does the ConfigMap also have the Helm hook annotations?  A DaemonSet runs one replica on every node in the cluster, and it's usually expected to be a long-running process; starting a new one as a side effect of uninstalling a chart seems unusual to me.

Comment: Configmap did not have. I added to it and it did not even register the configmap name when I did that. Is there something wrong with the way the hooks are written?

Comment: the idea is to delete few rpms installed in the node while removing the pack. hence added a pre-delete hook, which does the clean up @DavidMaze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary design point for Helm hooks is to run Jobs.  You can sort of use them to load things your Job needs like ServiceAccounts and ConfigMaps.  It won't really work well to use them to load a DaemonSet, especially in a pre-delete hook.

The [Helm hook documentation](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/) notes:

> If the resource is a `Job` or `Pod` kind, Helm will wait until it successfully runs to completion.  [...] For all other kinds, as soon as Kubernetes marks the resource as loaded (added or updated), the resource is considered "Ready".

In your setup, you have a pre-delete DaemonSet.  That's not a Job or a bare Pod, so Helm sends the DaemonSet definition to Kubernetes; once it's done that, possibly before any individual Pods are created, Helm then sends the delete request for everything else in the chart.

This is where the hook annotation on the ConfigMap matters.  If the ConfigMap is also annotated as a pre-delete hook, then it won't be installed as part of the main `helm install` content, but it will be loaded when the DaemonSet is.  If it isn't, then it will be uninstalled immediately after the DaemonSet is sent to the cluster.

The other challenge you may be running into is the `helm.sh/hook-delete-policy: hook-succeeded` annotation.  It's not clearly documented what "succeeded" means for long-running workload resources.  If "succeeded" just means "submitted to the cluster without error" this could cause the DaemonSet to be sent and then immediately deleted.

The only concrete suggestion I have here is to make a second copy of the ConfigMap that the hook can use.  I could imagine writing a dedicated DaemonSet that did mostly sat idle but the cleanup work when it received SIGTERM, which could then run as a normal DaemonSet without being a Helm hook.  The use case seems unusual to me, especially the comment about needing to manipulate software on the host, since everything in Kubernetes usually runs in a container and can't see or affect the host filesystem at all.

Comment: The only error I am not able to bypass is configmap "delete-pack" not found. It is almost as if the hook doesn't work as pre-delete. I loaded the hook in both configmap and daemonset.

Comment: pre-delete Executes on a deletion request before any resources are deleted from Kubernetes. This is the definition of a pre-delete hook. Will it help in removing the hook definition from the daemonset?

Comment: There is a consistent sequence of events where (1) Helm sends the DaemonSet definition to the cluster as the pre-delete hook; (2) Helm deletes the ConfigMap and the rest of the main chart content; (3) the cluster starts creating Pods from the DaemonSet, at which point the dependent ConfigMap is missing.

Comment: How does the helm send the daemonset definition as pre delete? due to the hook annotations in daemonset or configmap? When I put the annotations in configmap, the map is not even registered among the configmaps in the namespace. I am sure it is not namespace issue since I am able to see it being registered, when it is in daemonset alone

Comment: can you point me towards the logs I should be observing to know the issue deeper? I tried removing hook succeeded and just held with before-hook-creation and this caused the hook to stay in the node, even after deleting / recreating the node.